# Applying css to a php table

Tags: php, html, css

I have a generated php table which I would like to apply style in my style sheet, so for example top:15px, left:10px ect..., not sure how call the table and link it with css -

```
echo "<table border=1>";
for ($i=0;$i<count($calls);$i++){
  for ($j=0;$j<count($days);$j++){
    $k = $days[$i].$times[$j];
    if (array_key_exists($k,$date)){
      echo "<td colspan='{$date[$k][1]}'>".
           "{$date[$k][0]}</td>";
      $j+=$date[$k][1]-1;
    }else
      echo "<td style='color:gray'>$k</td>";
  }

  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

any help much appreciated, thank you

Comment: did you include a css file somewhere in the head of your document?

Comment: Which part do you not know how to do: Add a stylesheet to your page? Modify this PHP to include classes or ids on the table? Modify your CSS to apply to this table?

Comment: `table td` or `table tr` or by class or by ID, what exactly do you need?

Comment: Damien - I would like to have control over the whole table

Answer (score 3):

```
echo '<table style="top: 15px; left:10px;">';
```

or

```
echo '<table class="someClass">';
```

and then use CSS

```
.someClass{
top: 15px;
left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Give the table an `id`

```
echo "<table id=\"my_table\" border=1>";
```

And then use this in the `<head>` tag of the document:

```
<style type="text/css">

  #my_table {
    top: 15px;
    ...
  }

</style>
```

Comment: I can see a syntax-error in the PHP part of your answer from a mile away :)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<table style=\"border: 1px; top:15px; left: 10px;\">";
```

Is this statement not working?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<table border=1 style=\"top:15px; left:10px\">";

for ($i=0; $i<count($calls); $i++) {
    for ($j=0;$j<count($days);$j++) {
        $k = $days[$i].$times[$j];

        if (array_key_exists($k,$date)) {
            echo "<td colspan='{$date[$k][1]}'>".
                 "{$date[$k][0]}</td>";
            $j+=$date[$k][1]-1;
        } else {
            echo "<td style='color:gray'>$k</td>";
        }
    }

    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```