# Applying custom font to table cell inside PHP echo

Tags: php, html, fonts, echo

I am currently working on a project which pulls in tables from a mySQL which are shown in a html table. Below you can see the code.

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
    // yes 
    // print them one after another 
    echo "<table cellpadding=1 border=1 width=100%>"; 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) { 
        echo "<tr>";  
                echo "<td>"."<center>".$row[0]."</center>"."</td>"; 

        echo "<td>" .$row[2]."</td>"; 
        echo "<td>" .$row[1]."</td>"; 
        echo "<td>" .$row[3]."</td>";  
        echo "</tr>"; 
    } 
    echo "</table>"; 
}
```

I need to change it to

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
    // yes 
    // print them one after another 
    echo "<table cellpadding=1 border=1 width=100%>"; 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) { 
        echo "<tr>";  
                echo "<td>"."<center>".$row[0]."</center>"."</td>"; 

        echo "<td>" .$row[2]."</td>"; 
        echo "<td>" .$row[1]."</td>"; 
        echo "<td><font face="Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif">" .$row[3]."</font></td>";    
        echo "</tr>"; 
    } 
    echo "</table>"; 
}
```

When I do this is throws back errors. I am doing this so the user sees a barcode which i have a font for.

Am I doing this wrong? or is there another method which will work better.

Thanks
Ryan

Comment: whats the error can you post it here?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change " to ' for face:

```
 echo "<td><font face='Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif'>" .$row[3]."</font></td>";
```

Also instead of inline font you should use css class or id. (check this for example of css class [Applying css to a php table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175843/applying-css-to-a-php-table))

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo "<td><font face='Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif'>" .$row[3]."</font></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

OMG.. don't use `font` tag. It's deprecated since HTML 4.01 and not available in HTML 5. The error comes from not escaping properly.

```
echo "<td><font face=\"Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif\">" ...
```

But please use a class and do the styling with CSS.

```
echo "<td class=\"font-georgia\">...
```

And in css:

```
.font-georgia {
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
```

Note the quotes for `'Times New Roman'` because it has spaces.

The same for `center` tag. Use `text-align:center` CSS instead.